# avconv overlay for live video

Tags: video-streaming, libav

I want to combine two stream and I want a single stream with both video in a single stream by  simultaniously, both stream want to be visible at a time left half first video should be there and  right half second video should be there, I have tried with the overlay but as I am a new one to the avconv I am unable to get the desire result, I have given the code below which I have tried

```
avconv -i "rtmp://localhost/live/mystream1 live=1" -i "rtmp://localhost/live/mystream2 live=1" -i test.png -filter_complex nullsrc=size=526:340,overlay=0:0,overlay=10:20,scale=50:50,scale=50:50  -vcodec libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -b 256k -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

while using this command I am getting the following error

```
Error while filtering.
Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 00000000030E95A0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=       2kB time=0.03 bitrate= 488.0kbits/s
video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3676.190476%
[libx264 @ 00000000007BBDE0] final ratefactor: 108.44
```

Comment: I would recommend restoring the `ffmpeg` tag, since most of the users who are able to help you will be following that tag, rather than `libav`, and the projects are similar enough that advice for one is *normally* applicable to the other.

Comment: yes, I could but what ever working on the ffmpeg is not exactly working in avconv thats why I didnt put, any way I welcome your suggestion, and also I want the out put on avconv, I am not going to stick on the above command line so if you have any other way to achieve this your welcome.

Comment: @evilsoup I don't recommend using the ffmpeg tag for libav. These are not the same projects and could further promote confusion for users.